# Find energies of eigenstates?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, energy, harmonic-oscillator

I am given the potential $V(x,y,z)=\frac{1}{2} m \omega^2 (x^2+y^2+z^2)$ and I want to find the energies of the eigenstates for this system.
I know one way to find them is by using $H \psi_n=E_n \psi_n$ but is this even helpful here? I'm not given $\psi_n$, what should I do?

Comment: Have you covered the one dimensional harmonic oscillator in class?

Comment: I am actually self-studying quantum mechanics.

Comment: I know that the raising and lowering operators are used in such cases, but I don't know how.

Answer (score 3):

First you should write the Hamiltonian which is 
$$H(x,y,z) = - \frac{\hbar^2}{2m}\left(\frac{\partial^2}{\partial x^2} + \frac{\partial^2}{\partial y^2} + \frac{\partial^2}{\partial z^2} \right) + V(x,y,z)$$
and note that this Hamiltonian is the sum of three independent functions
$$H(x,y,z) = H_\mathrm{osc}(x)+H_\mathrm{osc}(y)+H_\mathrm{osc}(z)$$
where 
$$H_\mathrm{osc}(\xi) =- \frac{\hbar^2}{2m} \frac{\partial^2}{\partial \xi^2} + \frac12 m\omega^2\xi^2 $$
so the solution may be written as 
$$\psi_{n_xn_yn_z}(x,y,z) = \psi^\mathrm{osc}_{n_x}(x)\psi^\mathrm{osc}_{n_y}(y)\psi^\mathrm{osc}_{n_z}(z)$$
where $\psi^\mathrm{osc}$ are solution of 1D oscillator, see [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_harmonic_oscillator)

Answer (score 1):

When the potential is separable, i.e. when it can be written as 
$$
V=V(x)+V(y)+V(z)
$$
then often times the Hamiltonian is also separable:
$$
H=H(x)+H(y)+H(z)\, .
$$
As always one converts the partial differential equations for each coordinates to ordinary differential equations by assuming the solution is separable: $\psi=\psi(x)\phi(y)\xi(z)$ so that
$$
H(x)\psi(x)=E_x\psi(x)\, ,\quad H(y)\phi(y)=E_y\, ,\quad
H(z)\xi(z)=E_z\xi(z)\, . \tag{1}
$$
where the separation constants $E_x+E_y+E_z=E$, the total energy of the system.

In your case, (1) will be an independent Schrodinger equation in $x$, $y$ and $z$ coordinates respectively, so you can lift the solutions to the 1d problems and glue them together to get
$$
\psi_{n_xn_yn_z}(x,y,z)=\psi_{n_x}(x)\psi_{n_y}(y)\psi_{n_z}(z)\, .
$$

In your case, each $\psi_{n}(\zeta)$ is a 1d harmonic oscillator wave function in the appropriate variable, and the total energy is thus $\hbar\omega\left( n_x+\frac{1}{2}+n_y+\frac{1}{2}+n_z+\frac{1}{2}\right)=\left(N+\frac{3}{2}\right)\hbar\omega$ with $N=n_x+n_y+n_z$.  The solutions for which the triples $(n_x,n_y,n_z)$ add to the same $N$ have the same energy.  Thus for instance $(1,4,2)$ and $(4,2,1)$ have the same energy but corresponding to distinct wave functions.

As a point of note this problem is interesting because the 3D isotropic harmonic oscillator can be separated and solved completely in more than one coordinate system, i.e. separation occurs in Cartesian coordinates, in cylindrical, in spherical polar and others as well.  It is not often that potential can be separated and completely in many coordinate systems. (Obviously the solutions in spherical or cylindrical coordinates are not in terms of Hermite polynomials.)